# Can I use the recycling bin of a residence or business that's out on the street?

Tags: united-states, property, municipal-bylaws

Oftentimes I'll be carrying around some piece of recycling until I can find an appropriate recycling bin. There are usually public garbage cans everywhere, but sometimes there aren't any recycling bins to be found. If it happens to be collection day and some house or business's recycling bin is out on the curbside, is it okay to put something in as I'm walking by?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can determine, Washington does not have criminal laws that criminalize depositing your recycling in another person's recycling bin. It is illegal to divert recyclables from someone's container, and "dumping" is a crime. So it is probable that you will not be prosecuted. However, there could be a civil issue, i.e. the property owner could file suit against you for damages. The owner might be annoyed that you used his bin and might sue you, but be unable to prove that he was actually harmed (being annoyed is not a form of legal harm).
It's hard to see how putting stuff in someone else's bin could cause damage, but there are two main ways. First, the owner could be subject to a penalty if the material deposited is "illegal", which could refer to dirty paper, the wrong grade of plastic, sharp objects, light bulbs... Second, you might fill his bin making it impossible for him to recycle his own stuff. There, it depends on how strict the operation is in terms of the container and any overflow.

It would depends on what the laws of your state and municipality are, however.

Comment: I think he means that the person owning the recycling bin would say he is using their  resources, as in they have to pay to have it dumped.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage and recycling laws are very location specific in the sense that some municipalities deem garbage to be city/county property once it is out on the curb or put in the the city/county owned bin. Many recycling laws follow garbage laws, and also differ in that private companies often administer recycling for a city/county, and they sometimes "own" the recyclables once they are on the curb or in a bin. These details are all stipulated in the contract each business or person has with the recycler, as well as the contract the city/county has the with recycler.

Now, I doubt anyone will realistically care if you add one item to a recycling bin that is not technically yours, and add it correctly, i.e., not put glass in the metal bin. But someone could object, if the business or residence owner pays for recycling, if the recycling company restricts the use of bins to each account holder, etc.; there are many possibilities. So check with your specific city and county and read the current laws.

Comment: What is deemed garbage is related to searches in criminal cases, not this.

Comment: I've heard towns declaring garbage their properties because people were scavenging the "garbage" for usable things that could be turned into money - nothing wrong with that - and leaving an almighty mess behind as a result. So now if you leave mess behind, you can be charged with theft.

Answer (score -1):

That is up to them, we can't give you permission or take away permission to use someone else's property.

However, the police wouldn't do anything other than tell you to stop if someone had an issue.